# What deep learning model to use for NLP?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp

I am to make a model that takes a text and a list of keywords as input, and is to give a boolean value as output.
The model must output whether or not the text is relevant in relation to those keywords.
I don't know where to start or what model to use.
LSTM is typically used in NLP, but it only takes some text as input and predicts the next word, so I don't know if it can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are attempting to solve is called text classification.

LSTMs could be used for your problem. They can be used for predicting the next word in a sentence, but not necessarily. In general, the network takes the input word by word (or by subwords or characters) and updates its hidden state based on that. These states can be used for predicting what the next word is, but necessarily. You can, for instance, take the final states of the network and run a classifier on top of it. In this case, LSTMs are usually bidirectional: there are two networks, each of them running from a different end of the text.

A more recent popular alternative to LSTMs is the Transformer architecture. Using the pre-trained BERT model seems like a good solution to your problem, e.g., using the [Huggingface implementation in Pytorch](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers).

Comment: can you please answer this question, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69107390/implication-of-deep-learning-model-on-nlp-tabular-data